# NotImplementedException -- but it's something that should never be called

Tags: c#, exception, resharper

Logically the methods in question should be abstract but they are on a parent form that gets inherited from and Visual Studio will have fits if they are declared abstract.

Ok, I made the bodies throw a `NotImplementedException`. Resharper flags that and I'm not one to tolerate a warning in the code like that.

Is there an elegant answer to this or do I have to put up with some ugliness?  Currently I am doing:

```
protected virtual void SaveCurrentItem()
{
    Trace.Assert(false, "Only the children of FormCore.SaveCurrentItem should be called");
}

protected virtual void SetItem()
{
    Trace.Assert(false, "Only the children of FormCore.SetItem should be called");
}
```

The class itself should never be instantiated, only its children.  However, Visual Studio insists on creating one when you look at the designer of one of its children.

Comment: Hi, gould you please share your code? Thanks

Comment: If you want alternative designs, you need to describe your current design more fully, I think.

Comment: Perhaps you can move these methods to a non-form class? It looks like they might be business logic, which would be better placed outside of the UI code anyway..

Comment: @Blorgbeard Each form is an editor for a different type of data--the methods load/save between an object and the on-screen fields.  Thus they are UI, not business logic.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider creating a nested, protected interface. For example:

```
protected interface IManageItems
{
    void SaveCurrentItem();
    void SetItem();
}
```

Each class that inherits from FormCore could individually implement the interface. Then you wouldn't have the risk of calling the base class implementation because there wouldn't be any.

To call the methods from your base class:

```
(this as IManageItems)?.SaveCurrentItem();
```

This would have the effect of making the methods act as if they were `virtual` without having an initial declaration in the parent class. If you wanted to force a behavior that was closer to `abstract`, you could check to see if the interface was being implemented in the constructor of the base class and then throw an exception if it wasn't. Things are obviously getting a little wonky here, because this is essentially a workaround for something the IDE is preventing you from doing, and as such there's no real clean, standard solution for something like this. I'm sure most people would cringe at the sight of a nested protected interface, but if you don't want an implementation in your base class and you can't mark your base class abstract, you don't have a lot of options.

Another thing to consider is [favoring composition over inheritance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) to provide the functionality that you need.

---

On the other hand instead of using an interface, it may be appropriate to simply throw a `NotSupportedException` in a circumstance where the class cannot perform the action. `NotImplementedException` is designed to be used for in-development projects only, which is why ReSharper is flagging the method.

> NotSupportedException: The exception that is thrown when an invoked method is not supported, or when there is an attempt to read, seek, or write to a stream that does not support the invoked functionality.

One use case is:

> You've inherited from an abstract class that requires that you override a number of methods. However, you're only prepared to provide an implementation for a subset of these. For the methods that you decide not to implement, you can choose to throw a NotSupportedException.

See [NotSupportedException documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notsupportedexception(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information and usage guidelines.

Comment: As @Rob mentions in his answer, it's about the intention. If you never intend to, or simply cannot logically, implement the method, the NotSupportedException (in my mind, at least) has more of a finality to it, whereas the NotImplementedException could be viewed as a mistake by the next developer to come along.

Comment: It's just that it's not something that ever should be supported.  The right declaration is *abstract* but the IDE won't tolerate it.

Comment: It would be nice to have a compile-time error when the method is not overridden, though.

Comment: @LorenPechtel The right declaration is not abstract, since you're specifically allowing instances of the class by not making the class abstract. What would you expect to happen if they invoke the method?

Comment: @Rob this is a base class that would normally be an *abstract* base class, but cannot be abstract because it inherits from Form, and the VS designer will try to instantiate it. We're looking for the next best way to declare methods that "must" be overridden and cannot have their base versions called.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect the example code - please advise if it is more appropriate to create a different answer in this circumstance as I'm still new

Comment: I can't see how this would work--the methods are in the base class because the base class calls them.

Comment: Updated again with clarification and another example

Answer (score 1):

Resharper raises the warning to alert users that code has not been completed. If your actual desired behaviour is to not support those methods, you should throw a `NotSupportedException` instead of `NotImplementedException`, to make your intentions clearer.